# Should i instantiate a new model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, class

MVC.  I am passing data to the view in my model.  In my repository I map the linq result to the model.  In the controller I send the data.  Which one should I do:

```
List<PersonModel> people = new List<PersonModel>();
people = repo.GetPersonList();
return View(people);
```

Or

```
List<PersonModel> people = repo.GetPersonList();
return View(people);
```

As I mentioned, in the repo I map the result to the model, with a new model instance:

```
var query = from p in _db.Person
                     orderby f.LastName
                     select new PersonModel
                     {
                         Id = f.PersonId,
                         LastName = f.LastName
                     };
return query.ToList();
```

Either one works.  I use the second one because by my thinking, the repo is creating a new model then passing it to the controller when I call the repo.GetPersonList function.  Should I create a new instance in the controller as well, or continue as I am?

Comment: I prefer the send one. It is more readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go with the second.

Your first snippet has a redundant `new List<T>` call which allocates a new list, while the next line overrides that reference with a newly created list from your `repo`. Absolutely no need for that.

Answer (score 1):

If, on your Controller, it's responsibility of the `repository` to provide the ViewModel and you don't indend to allow the Controller to add a new `PersonModel` to the ViewModel, then you should definitely stick to the **second one**.